# combining paging and list of android in one view

Tags: android

I am new in programming to android now my work is paused as I am not getting how to accomplish the following I want to create a view which will have paging capability and in the view there would be textview to display the name of person and a list of name of all his relatives .... And the list can be long so it should be scrollable... I know to do paging and list independently but do not know how to combine the both in one view.... I hope I am clear with my question... So guys help me how to accomplish this...

Comment: what you used for paging???

Comment: Post code i will show how can you combine

Comment: Posting code not possible as per my company policy...sorry... Any other you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I know to do paging and list independently but do not know how to combine the both in one view
```

So you can create xml like this :

- Linear Layout/ Relative layout
- Text View
- List View

Put this XML in fragment

**EDIT** :

```
public class Fragment1test extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //This layout contains your list view 
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_view_xml, container, false);

           //now you must initialize your list view
           Listview listview =(Listview)view.findViewById(R.id.your_listview);


           //Here items must be a List<Items> according to your class instead of String[] array
           ListAdapter listadapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
           ListView.setAdapter( listAdapter());

           //getActivty is used instead of Context
         return view;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ok I tried that ... But not getting idea how to bind data to list view... Kindly help with example

Comment: As u said "**I know to do paging and list independently but do not know how to combine the both in one view**", u must have done listview

Comment: I have done listview creating XML file with required control and than using class extending arrayadapter ...not using list view

Comment: Have a look on [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments)

Comment: You done it with fragment, I told pit this code in XML and inflate it in fragment

Comment: You can google it dude.. check [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=listview+in+fragment+android+example&oq=listview+in+fragmwn&aqs=chrome.3.57j0l3.7129j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8|)

Comment: Idea not working ... List working independently but paging not happening... I need paging and list in on view